# Script telnet on webserver

Tags: bash, scripting, telnet

I would like to script telnet to test my website inputs handling. I can do it manually :

```
telnet localhost 8888
...
GET / HTTP/1.1\n
Host: localhost


...html response
```

But I can pass command to telnet in my shell script !

I've tried :

```
(echo "GET / HTTP/1.1\n"; echo "Host: localhost \n\n"; sleep 1) | telnet localhost 8888
```

It produces no results at all !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Probably not the only issue)
You should "echo -en", and use single quote to close strings. This makes bash interpret \n correctly

Regards

Answer (score 3):

I find that `netcat`, aka `nc`, is much better suited to this sort of task.

Also as Giuseppe mentions you'll have to fix the quoting.  An alternative to `bash -e` is to quote using `$'this form'`, in which `\n`, `\t`, etc. are interpreted by `bash` when parsing the command line rather than being passed on to `echo`.  So that form is applicable to many different utilities.

Comment: Also, recent versions of bash recognize the "/dev/tcp/host/port" pseudofile. By using this feature (if available) telnet isn't necessary anymore. Bye

Comment: afaik, /dev/tcp is not a feature of bash, it's dependent on the kernel config, or enabled modules, or ..something.  Anyway some distros (including ubuntu and I believe most debian-likes) don't have this facility.
But I could be wrong.. is there a better way to check than `ls /dev/tcp`?  This gives me "No such file or directory" under ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: It depends on the build. Here's what "man bash" says on my Ubuntu:
       Bash handles several filenames specially when they are used in redirections, as described in the following table:
[...]
              /dev/tcp/host/port
                     If host is a valid hostname or Internet address, and port
                     is  an integer port number or service name, bash attempts
                     to open a TCP connection to the corresponding socket.
            NOTE: Bash, as packaged for Debian, does not support using the /dev/tcp
       and /dev/udp files.

Comment: (continue) So it depends on the particular build. Anyway it's not a kernel feature. The Debian (and Ubuntu) one doesn't actually support it. Regards

Comment: weird.  I always thought that was implemented with a device driver, but it's actually a bash issue.  Also it looks like the bash that is current in Karmic (Ubuntu 9.10) is actually compiled with this feature.  I stand corrected.    More on the history of the issue at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/215034

Comment: It's notable that this is just something that `bash` does, so other programs can't direct/get output/input to/from a `/dev/tcp` location.  well at least not without going through `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

The usual answer to "How do I script x?" is "[`expect`](http://expect.nist.gov/)"